# How to deploy a specific stack using AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In my AWS CDK/ Typescript project I have 1 main stack i.e. `aws-microservices-stack.ts`

rest all typescript files are just constructs extended in `aws-microservices-stack.ts`

[image]

But when I run `cdk deploy` I get error

> Since this app includes more than a single stack, specify which stacks
> to use (wildcards are supported) or specify `--all` Stacks:
> AwsMicroservicesStack · AwsMicroservicesStack/Database ·
> AwsMicroservicesStack/Microservices · AwsMicroservicesStack/ApiGateway

How can I mark `aws-microservices-stack.ts` so that deploy command picks up only that stack

**aws-microservices-stack.ts**

```
import { Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';;
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { SwnApiGateway } from './apigateway';
import { SwnDatabase } from './database';
import { SwnMicroServices } from './microservices';

export class AwsMicroservicesStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const database = new SwnDatabase(this, 'Database');
....

  }
}
```

**database.ts**

```
import { RemovalPolicy, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { AttributeType, BillingMode, ITable, Table } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';


export class SwnDatabase extends Stack {

  public readonly productTable: ITable;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    // DynamoDb Table
    const productTable = new Table(this, 'product', {

      partitionKey: {
        name: 'id',
        type: AttributeType.STRING
      },
      tableName: 'product',
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST
    });

    this.productTable = productTable;


  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "mark" it for deployment, you need to specify which stack to deploy with:

```
cdk deploy $yourstackname
```

The names of the declares stacks are listed by

```
cdk ls
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html) you can read more about cdk stacks handling.

Comment: I found out my issue was that I was extending, Stack instead of construct, so cdk was getting confused which stack to deploy.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
cdk deploy $stack_name --exclusively
```

From the CLI help docs:

> -e, --exclusively          Only deploy requested stacks, don't include
> dependencies                              [boolean]

Answer (score 1):

With specific profile and region
`cdk deploy <stackname> --profile <profilename> --region <region>`